# Passenger keeps looking for wrong ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I upgrade my ruby version to 2.6.5. I deployed it to my server using capistrano.

But my nginx logs say this:

```
App 9470 output: /bin/sh: 1: exec: /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/wrappers/ruby: not found
[ E 2022-01-27 12:34:23.7336 9450/Tc age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:221 ]: Could not spawn process for application /home/deploy/taddar/current: The application process exited prematurely.
  Error ID: d1f83ca0
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-0KwZUf.html

[ E 2022-01-27 12:34:23.7393 9450/T9 age/Cor/Con/CheckoutSession.cpp:276 ]: [Client 1-1] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is d1f83ca0. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
```

When I run `ruby -v` I get 2.6.5, yet above you can see its looking for 2.3.1:

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [x86_64-linux]
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

In my deploy.rb I set the ruby version.

```
set :rvm_ruby_version, '2.6.5'
```

My nginx.config looks like:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {
        passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby2.6.5;

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        underscores_in_headers on;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include      /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_min_length 256;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf font/opentype image/svg+xml image/x-icon;

        ##
        # Phusion Passenger config
        ##
        # Uncomment it if you installed passenger or passenger-enterprise
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/passenger.conf;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Comment: What do you have in `nginx.config`? Look for https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/reference/#passenger_ruby and set the correct path to ruby.

Comment: @razvans Thanks for your reply. Im not really a dev ops guy but if you're referring too `/etc/nginx/nginx.config` it was empty. Does the below look like its ok? Or did I need the rest of the config file?
```
http {
    passenger_root ...;

    # Use Ruby 2.1 by default.
    passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby2.6.5;
}
```

Comment: @razvans I updated my question to include the nginx.config. I deployed again and restarted nginx and passenger just incase and still get the same error in the logs. Any other ideas?

Comment: Any reference to passenger_ruby inside the files from sites-enabled ?

Comment: 2 things. 1 chances are that there is a reference in the site specific config as mentioned by @razvans; 2. I am not sure what you mean by you "upgraded" ruby but this system appears to have rvm installed (or at least the config error suggests it does), in this case you should install rubies through rvm e.g. `rvm install 2.6.5` and then reference the rvm installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bingo got it working. Thanks to @razvans and @engineersmnky for pointing me in the right direction.

Yes I had references to `passenger_ruby` but it was in the wrong place. I had to go to `/etc/nginx/sites-available` and add `passenger_ruby /path/to/ruby`

To find out what the `/path/to/ruby` is use `passenger-config about ruby-command` and use the value at `Command`.

```
passenger-config about ruby-command
passenger-config was invoked through the following Ruby interpreter:
  Command: /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/wrappers/ruby
```

So mine was

```
server {
 ....
 passenger_ruby /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/wrappers/ruby
```

You might want to know any other references you have to ruby so they don't conflict with each other. A useful command is: `grep -rnw 'path' -e 'passenger_ruby'`

This doc helped me a lot https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/nginx/deploy/ruby/#determine_ruby_command